# Theme.AppCompat on floatingActionButton sdk 18

Tags: android, android-appcompat, floating-action-button

Well, I have been searching an answer and still no results so I must do the question. The fact is that I'm seting the AppCompat to the context of a custom class that inherits FloatingActionButton, but still having the error:

```
You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
```

This is the code fragment Where I'm creating the float button:

```
                    Heap properties = new Heap(part);
                    context.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
                    SocialNetwork socialBtn = new SocialNetwork(context);
                    socialBtn.setAlpha(0.8f);
                    socialBtn.setScaleX(0.85f);
                    socialBtn.setScaleY(0.85f);
                    socialBtn.setClickable(false);
                    socialBtn.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#FAFAFA")));
                    InputStream is;
                    try {
                        is = context.getAssets().open("social_icons/" + properties.get("icon"));
                        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                        socialBtn.setImageBitmap(icon);
                        socialBtn.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams btnParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                    );

                    socialBtnsContainer.addView(socialBtn, btnParams);
```

And this is my custon Class code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;

public class SocialNetwork extends FloatingActionButton {

    public SocialNetwork(Context context) {
         super(context);
    }
}
```

and this is the Error:

```
                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{co.cardseed.cardseed/co.cardseed.cardseed.activities.CardseedActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
                                                                      at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:33)
                                                                      at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:159)
                                                                      at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:153)
                                                                      at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:149)
                                                                      at co.cardseed.cardseed.components.type.SocialNetwork.<init>(SocialNetwork.java:16)
                                                                      at co.cardseed.cardseed.components.type.Type$1.Run(Type.java:178)
                                                                      at co.cardseed.cardseed.components.heap.Heap.execute(Heap.java:246)
                                                                      at co.cardseed.cardseed.components.heap.Heap.forEach(Heap.java:238)
                                                                      at co.cardseed.cardseed.components.type.Type.buildType(Type.java:173)
                                                                      at co.cardseed.cardseed.app.configs.Card$1.Run(Card.java:164)
                                                                      at co.cardseed.cardseed.components.heap.Heap.execute(Heap.java:246)
                                                                      at co.cardseed.cardseed.components.heap.Heap.forEach(Heap.java:238)
                                                                      at co.cardseed.cardseed.components.heap.Heap.forEach(Heap.java:239)
                                                                      at co.cardseed.cardseed.components.heap.Heap.forEach(Heap.java:239)
                                                                      at co.cardseed.cardseed.components.heap.Heap.forEach(Heap.java:239)
                                                                      at co.cardseed.cardseed.components.heap.Heap.forEach(Heap.java:239)
                                                                      at co.cardseed.cardseed.app.configs.Card.buildCard(Card.java:137)
                                                                      at co.cardseed.cardseed.models.beans.User.<init>(User.java:55)
                                                                      at co.cardseed.cardseed.app.App.setMainActivity(App.java:170)
                                                                      at co.cardseed.cardseed.activities.CardseedActivity.onCreate(CardseedActivity.java:50)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003) 
                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My gradle config:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "co.cardseed.cardseed"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
        }
    }
}

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

Comment: Try using a `ContextThemeWrapper` instead. `ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.AppTheme);`, then use that to instantiate your `SocialNetwork` button (if you're certain `AppTheme` extends `Theme.AppCompat`).

Comment: Yeah, the parent is Theme.AppCompat. I'll try.